# Firebase for Play Services below 9

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

**The Background**

My app is heavily dependent on Firebase. I use most of the services like Authentication, Realtime database, Storage, Analytics, Crash Reporting and more.

Everything works fine so far, but I have a doubt regarding a particular scenario.

**The Problem**

As Firebase was introduced in Play Services 9, what will happen to those devices who have still not updated to Play Services 9.

1. How will my app work on those devices as my app is heavily dependent on Firebase?
2. How does Firebase cater to the scenario of backporting?
3. Or should the developers some how check the version of Play Services and request the user to update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How will my app work on those devices as my app is heavily dependent on Firebase?

When installing the application, it will prompt them a message saying that this app requires a higher version of Play Services. So it **will** work properly.

> How does Firebase cater to the scenario of backporting?

Firebase needs a minimum API of 9. If the device doesn't support anything that's missing from the device, it will simply tell them, so you don't have to worry.

> Or should the developers some how check the version of Play Services and request the user to update?

**NO**, Android does this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

i have edited my answer to make things a bit more clear

**1. How will my app work on those devices as my app is heavily dependent on Firebase?**

Android automatically checks for the play services version that is currently installed in the user's device and prompts the user to update to the play services version that the application was built with Firebase.

**2. How does Firebase cater to the scenario of backporting?**

Firebase explicitly outlines the latest version of play services as a prerequisite for building with it, there is no information on the docs about back porting so I don't think it is possible at the moment.

**3. Or should the developers some how check the version of Play Services and request the user to update?**

I wouldn't recommend this as Android already checks and pops up a play services error. However it is quite possible to check the version of play services and request the user to first update it in order to use your application, more info on this can be found on this link [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context))

Comment: Please give your answer better formatting by answering each question one by one instead of giving a paragraph that doesn't make things too clear