# What is minimum version of Google Play Services to use Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

## Background

I'm developing an app using `Firebase` features (`Realtime Database`, `Firebase Messaging,` `Analytics`, `Crash Reporting` and `Auth` [`Facebook`]). In my country, most of the users don't have wifi and rarely upgrade apps (including `Google Play Services`).

## Question

1. As the title suggests, I would like to know the minimum version (the lowest). I'm also willing to remove some features if it will help to lower the Google Play Services version.
2. Do I need to check google play service version in my application code or will Firebase check for me?

## Finding so far and I'm confused,

- [This post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebase-talk/M8Rop0IMsSw/discussion) say min version is 9.0
- [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!msg/firebase-talk/VB_MqWdP30k/QJk_vd2EAgAJ) say min version is 8.1.15
- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627880/firebase-for-play-services-below-9) say developer no need to check `Google Play Services`
- but, [This doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play) say developer need to check `Google Play Services`

Comment: can someone let me know why it is down-voted? I'm happy to improve the question if you can tell me the reason.

Comment: firebase was officially added in 9.0

Answer (score 8):

The [most trustworthy site](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) says 9.0

> For a list of the libraries available for the different Firebase features, see Firebase libraries. The following features are now part of Firebase in the Google Play Services 9.0 SDK.

The current stable is 9.4.

https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Comment: yeah, but as from this link (https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!msg/firebase-talk/VB_MqWdP30k/QJk_vd2EAgAJ), Steve Ganem said it was Google Play services >= v8.1.15. If I'm not wrong, he is Product Manager at Google.

Comment: Yeah. Firebase might be unstable in that version. Just it is recommend to use 9.4.0 where lots of bugs are fixed.

Comment: Ninjs, yeah, as always - latest is the best. But in my country, people only use mobile data for internet. I don't want them to download and upgrade Google Play Services (45 MB) unless it is a must.

Comment: @SoeMoe - did u figure out the firebase version thing ? I want to maintain long backward compatibility and dont want to use firebase version which forces people to upgrade play services. would love to see how you managed this.

Comment: I have play service version -9.8.0 I want to know can i use firebase latest version here